# Implode() vs Foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, implode

Have those syntaxes:
Foreach:

```
$array=array('v1','v2','v3');
foreach( $array as $value ){
echo $value;
}
```

Output:

```
v1v2v3
```

Implode:

```
$array=array('v1','v2','v3');
$value=implode(" ",$array);
echo $value;
```

Output:

```
v1 v2 v3
```

I need some help understanding the difference between implode(),foreach() used in the situation above.Are they the same? Or what is the difference? Which i should use and when?

**For the record,i know small differences,and things like that.I just want to know your opinion and if there is something i didn't know about those functions.**

Comment: short answer: it depends, its depends on the situations, can be a myriad of results why you should choose the other

Comment: First snippet outputs v1v2v3 instead.

Comment: The result is obviously the same, the way to get there is different. Which to use depends on what's more appropriate and/or readable and/or understandable for the specific task. Personally, whenever I can do the same thing in one function call instead of a loop, I go for the function call.

Comment: @sectus , i think that is pretty obvious,but is not what i asked

Comment: @deceze , yes indeed,but have you any example? when i should use one and when the other?

Comment: `foreach` goes through all elements of an `array`. `implode` creates one `string` by sticking together all elements from an `array` using a "glue" in your example, a space `" "`

Comment: A loop is obviously a much more general construct than `implode`. Use as appropriate. You could do many different things in a loop. `implode` only does one specific thing.

Comment: @Memphistoles , you have showed different snippets, that makes different output and have asked 'What is the difference?'.

Comment: @sectus before you ask something like this,why dont you inform a little bit about the disscusions that have been done here? take a look below and above,and maybe you will figure out what i ment,because seems like others catched the idea

Comment: @Memphistoles, your question as pretty good example of 'xy-problem'. Your question is about 'Implode() vs Foreach()'. But you really want to know about approaches of working with databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally loops may be used for making any action you want.

You can for example concatenate string with other string depending or array element:

```
$array=array('v1','v2','v3');
foreach ($array as $value) {
  if ($value == 'v1') {
    echo $value.' something';
  } 
  else {
    echo $value.' something2';
  }
}
```

and if you have numbers in your array you can do math operations:

```
$array=array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $value) {
  echo ($value + 5).' ';
}
```

You can also change array elements:

```
$array=array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value += 3;
}
unset($value);
foreach ($array as $value ){
    echo $value.' ';
}
// result: 4 5 6
```

`Implode` is just a function that merge array elements and put a splitter between them. Nothing more. It doesn't change array elements. It simple returns output string. It's usually used for preparing data to display.

Also `implode` is much more convenient for putting splitter between elements. In loop if you want to put space between all elements but you don't need to put space after last element you need to make extra checks for last element and using `implode` you don't need to care because `implode` just does it for you.

And in your case, output wouldn't be the same because your loop would output:
`v1v2v3` and implode would output `v1 v2 v3` because you used space separator

Comment: so this is the only difference uh? i was afraid,that using implode,will cause an issues,but it is no different that foreach in my case,also foreach is more useful in many ways

Comment: very well explained,thanks a lot

Comment: @Memphistoles Loops are for more complex operations. If you just want to display elements separated by space you can use `implode`

Comment: Don't forget that if one wants the splitter only *between* the elements, one would have to take extra precautions when using foreach. This is where implode shines.

Comment: but in case,i fetch a query,then i use implode,converting them into string,and using them in a drop or create query?? would be better with foreach or implode??

Comment: @Memphistoles In that case you should rather use PDO/mysqli with prepared statements and not use implode just to put data into database because of possible SQL injection

Comment: @Yoshi Good point, I've added it to my answer

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek ,this is not what i ment,let me explain it better,i want to use some database datas,to create some copies of them,im not inserting anything from a form or something that can endanger my database

Comment: @Memphistoles Hard to say if we don't see your code and what really you want to achieve

Comment: Well its no use to post my code for just an opinion.I list the databases,then return them as array,i used implode to convert them into string so i can use them to make a duplicate of each db,with another query.And i dont know if would be better foreach than implode in this case,or doesnt matter??

Comment: @Memphistoles Using implode you would create string of all databases and it would be rather useless. In this case you should rather use loop (for example foreach) to go for database and create inside loop duplicate

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek , aham, well thanks a lot,that was perplexity,not it's all clear

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` is a loop statement. `implode` is a function. That's the difference. You are supposed to use `foreach` for any kind of operation for each element in an array. But `implode` is a helper method that binds the elements of the given array by using the given string as binder.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach()` : it's a looping concept means you get values one by one and print you will found each result/value seperate while you not concat that.

`implode()` : convert an array to string with passsing glue. and you will get all array values in one string.

Answer (score 1):

`implode()` also iterating array internally, and converting `array` into `string`

**loop**  is also doing same thing here,

**loop advantage here**

1) when you want to conditional part, for instance 
you want to exclude `v2` from string or other operation depend on requirement

```
$array=array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $value ){
  if($value == 2) continue;
   echo $value." ";
}
```

these things can't apply in `implode` function

2) In loop you can direct buffer output or append into string.. [this is denpend on requirement],

`import` is only function that is combine array values into string.

Answer (score 0):

how can it be same, both r used in different places. for example

```
list($y,$m,$d)=explode("-",$query); //separating and storing in variable `y-m-d` 
$arr=array($m,$d);
$cat=implode('-',$arr); //u got that format again with only two variables
```

implode expects array.

where foreach is a loop which iterates through given array() until and unless it meets the false condition and gets out of the loop