# How to get data from a string that's separated by commas

Tags: php, xml, preg-match

I have a string like this

```
url1, url2, url3, url4, url5
```

I'd like to separate each url like this using php

```
<fileurl>url1</fileurl>
<fileurl>url2</fileurl>
<fileurl>url3</fileurl>
```

What is the best way to do it - should I use preg_match?

Comment: Hey Vikki. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet - because I want to do it the correct way instead of guessing

Comment: Try `foreach (explode($str) as $url) { ... }`

Comment: Do you want to display the urls that way? I mean one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$string = "url1, url2, url3, url4, url5";
echo "<fileurl>" . implode('</fileurl><fileurl>', explode(', ', $string)) . "</fileurl>";
```

Explanation:

- Convert your comma separated string to an array using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- use closing and opening tags as a delimiter in [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, also make it wrap between opening and closing tags.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. So do you think explode and implode is better than using explode and foreach? Or is it just a matter of opinion?

Comment: It depends where you use it. implode is a function which converts an array to string with a separator, and serves your purpose. However, for each is an iterator and used to iterate through an array, objects (you can do multiple operations using loops). In this particular case, I would prefer to use implode as it serves the purpose.

also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928108/implode-vs-foreach

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode` like this:

```
$urls = "url1, url2, url3";
$urlsArray = explode(", ", $urls);

foreach($urlsArray as $url) {
    echo "<fileurl>".$url."</fileurl>";
}
```

Comment: Why foreach? If you are displaying all urls that way its pointless to use foreach. Instead use implode and explode

Comment: @Elanochecer there is no difference really. In the background there is a look doing the same thing anyways